# Remove duplicates from a list of objects based multiple attributes in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to compare getCode & getMode and find duplicate records.

Then there is one more product attribute getVode which always has different value(either true or false) in both records.

```
P1   getCode  getMode  getVode
1    001      123      true
P2   getCode  getMode  getVode
2    001      123      false
```

I tried below but it only finds duplicates:

```
List<ProductModel> uniqueProducts = productsList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<>(
            Comparator.comparing(ProductModel::getCode)
                .thenComparing(ProductModel::getMode)
        )),
        ArrayList::new));
```

So when I find duplicates records, I want to check the getVode value which is false and remove it from list.
Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: what if there are 3 entries with `001/123/false` and `001/123/true` _and_ `001/123/false`? remove where `false` is present?

Comment: @Eugene we have to remove all which are duplicates and having false for getVode

Comment: also... can there be more that one instances where `true` is present for `vode`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understood, you want to remove elements only if they are a duplicate *and* their `getVode` method returns `false`.

We can do this literally. First, we have to identify which elements are duplicates:

```
Map<Object, Boolean> isDuplicate = productsList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(pm -> Arrays.asList(pm.getCode(), pm.getMode()),
                              pm -> false, (a, b) -> true));
```

Then, remove those fulfilling the condition:

```
productsList.removeIf(pm -> !pm.getVode()
                         && isDuplicate.get(Arrays.asList(pm.getCode(), pm.getMode())));
```

Or, not modifying the old list:

```
List<ProductModel> uniqueProducts = new ArrayList<>(productsList);
uniqueProducts.removeIf(pm -> !pm.getVode()
                           && isDuplicate.get(Arrays.asList(pm.getCode(), pm.getMode())));
```

which can also be done via Stream operation:

```
List<ProductModel> uniqueProducts = productsList.stream()
    .filter(pm -> pm.getVode()
              || !isDuplicate.get(Arrays.asList(pm.getCode(), pm.getMode())))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I like very much the `merge()` trick to detect the duplication.

Comment: @Holger Very nice answer but one last question what if the value for getVode() is not of type boolean & it is of type string with? is it possible as removeif will work only for boolean type right?

Comment: Ask yourself, *when* should the elements be removed. Then, write the condition down as Java code, i.e. `pm.getVode().equals(…)` or `pm.getVode().matches(…)` etc.

Comment: Can we do this in Java 7 as well or is this possible only in java 8?

Comment: @User2413 there is no magic behind it, so you can write Java 7 code doing the same. But it won’t be as compact.

Answer (score 3):

Here you remove the duplicates whatever the `getVode()` value since it is not considered in the `Comparator` passed to the `TreeSet`.
Not easy with your approach.
You could create a `Map<ProductModelId, List<ProductModelId>>` by grouping the element according to their `getCode()` and `getMode()` values that you can represent with a `ProductModelId` class.
Then for each entry of the Map process it : if the list contains a single element, keep it, otherwise don't keep all these that have `getVode()` to false.

```
Map<ProductModelId, List<ProductModel>> map = 
productsList.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(p -> new ProductModelId(p.getCode(), p.getMode());

List<ProductModel> listFiltered =
        map.values()
           .stream()
           .flatMap(l -> {
                        if (l.size() == 1) {
                          return Stream.of(l.get(0));
                        } else {
                          return l.stream().filter(ProductModel::getVode);
                        }
                    }
           )
           .collect(toList());
```

Note that `ProductModelId` should override `equals/hashCode` by considering the value of the two fields to group them correctly in the map :

```
public class ProductModelId {

    private String code;
    private String mode;

    public ProductModelId(String code, String mode) {
        this.code = code;
        this.mode = mode;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof ProductModelId)) return false;
        ProductModelId that = (ProductModelId) o;
        return Objects.equals(code, that.code) &&
                Objects.equals(mode, that.mode);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(code, mode);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `map.values()` instead of `map.entrySet()` saves you from calling `getValue()` on the entries, when you are not interested in the keys. Further, replacing `if(condition) return a; else return b;` with `return condition? a: b;` allows you to change the lambda from statement syntax to expression syntax: `.flatMap(v -> v.size() == 1? Stream.of(v.get(0)): v.stream().filter(p -> !p.getVode()))`

Comment: Agreed for the first point. For the second, I am aware of it but generally I avoid ternary for not trivial statements associated to.

Comment: That’s ok, but the question is what makes a nontrivial statement. Perhaps, the noise of 14 tokens, where you only need two, is what makes it look nontrivial. You can do without the ternary, by the way, using `.flatMap(l -> l.stream().filter(p -> l.size() == 1 || p.getVode()))`, but I’d prefer the ternary. By the way, the `false` values are to be removed, but the `filter` predicate specifies which to keep, so it should be `p.getVode()` without `!`.

Comment: `.flatMap(l -> l.stream().filter(p -> l.size() == 1 || p.getVode()))` is a possibility, it is right but it associates comparisons that compare two distinct things : the list and the element :  I don't find it necessarily easily to read. For ternary it is probably a habit matter I assume.

Answer (score 0):

You could grouping by combination of code and mode. And then in mergeFunction get the element with `true` vode:

```
 Collection<ProductModel> uniqueProducts  = products.stream()
        .collect(toMap(
                    p -> Arrays.asList(p.getCode(), p.getMode()),
                    Function.identity(),
                    (p1, p2) -> p1.getVode() ? p1 : p2))
        .values();
```

See [javaDoc for toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-)

Comment: `p -> p.getCode() + p.getMode()` - terrible IMO, use `Arrays.asList`; but the merger is broken anyway, what if `p1.getVode` is `false`, but `p2.getVode` is `false` _too_?

Comment: @Eugene according to OP _there is one more product attribute getVode which  always has different value_. And agreed about `Arrays.asList`.. thanks

Comment: exactly the reason I asked a comment just under the question

Answer (score 0):

If your `vode` can be `true` for multiple instances of `ProductModel` (otherwise if you expect a single `true` - this is even simpler, I'll let this an exercise for you) and you want to retain them all, may be this is what you are after:

```
    List<ProductModel> models = List.of(
        new ProductModel(1, 123, false),
        new ProductModel(1, 123, true)); // just an example

    Map<List<Integer>, List<ProductModel>> map = new HashMap<>();

    models.forEach(x -> {

        map.computeIfPresent(Arrays.asList(x.getMode(), x.getCode()),
                             (key, value) -> {
                                 value.add(x);
                                 value.removeIf(xx -> !xx.isVode());
                                 return value;
                             });
        map.computeIfAbsent(Arrays.asList(x.getMode(), x.getCode()),
                            key -> {
                                List<ProductModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
                                list.add(x);
                                return list;
                            });
    });

    map.values()
       .stream()
       .flatMap(List::stream)
       .forEachOrdered(x -> System.out.println(x.getCode() + "  " + x.getMode()));
```

where `ProductModel` is something like:

```
    static class ProductModel {

    private final int code;
    private final int mode;
    private final boolean vode;

    // some other fields, getters, setters

}
```

This ins't that trivial to achieve. You first need to find if there are duplicates and only act accordingly when such are found. `map.computeIfAbsent` takes care to put into the map keys (a `Key` is made from `Code/Mode` wrapped in `Arrays::asList` - it properly overrides `hashCode/equals`).

When a duplicate is found based on that Key, we want to act on that via `map.computeIfPresent`. The "acting" isn't trivial either, considering that `vode` can be `true` across multiple instances (yes, this is my assumption). You don't know what `vode` was put into this map for the previous Key - was it `false`? if so, it mush be removed. But is the current `false` too? If so, it must be removed also.

Comment: Can i take this in to a list instead of map?

Comment: @ASMA2412 yeah... you could easily. just change `forEachOrdered(x -> System.out.println(x.getCode() + "  " + x.getMode()))` to `collect(Collectors.toList())`; but to be honest a better answer already was provided by Holger.